# mongodb aggregation sums of elements over all(specific) arrays in collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Maybe some can help me with that one.

I have a collection that contains data like this:

```
{
    "id" : 123,
    "country" : "US",
    "timestamp" : 1417904130
}
{
    "id" : 123,
    "country" : "DE",
    "timestamp" : 1417904136
}
{
    "id" : 111,
    "country" : "US",
    "timestamp" : 1417904512
}
{
    "id" : 111,
    "country" : "US",
    "timestamp" : 1417904777
}
...
```

I tried this:

```
db.countries_usg.aggregate( [ { $match: {}}, { $group: {'_id': "$id", 'countries': {'$addToSet': '$country'} }} ], {'allowDiskUse': true})
```

But this only gives me:

```
{ "_id" : 123, "languages" : [ "US", "DE" ] }
{ "_id" : 111, "languages" : [ "US" ] }
...
```

And i need this:

```
{ "_id" : 123, "languages" : [ "US": 1, "DE": 1 ] }
{ "_id" : 111, "languages" : [ "US": 2 ] }
...
```

Or similar. Someone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be achieved using two consecutive $group aggregations:

```
db.countries_usg.aggregate([
        { $group: {
            '_id': {id:"$id", "country" : "$country"},
            "count" : { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { $group: {
            '_id': "$_id.id",
            "countries" : {"$push" : {country:"$_id.country", count : "$count"}}
        }},
    ],
    {'allowDiskUse': true}
);
```

And the result will look like this:

```
{ "_id" : 123, "countries" : [ { "country" : "DE", "count" : 1 }, { "country" : "US", "count" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : 111, "countries" : [ { "country" : "US", "count" : 2 } ] }
```

Comment: Hey joao! Confirmed. This does exactly what i need. Thanks a lot; this is very helpfull!